# Under what practical scenario would you want a write-only property?

Tags: c#, object

When would you ever want to create an object that has a property that is write-only, but that you cannot read? Obviously the reverse (read-only) can be useful under many circumstances, but can somebody give me an example of a write-only property and when that would be useful?

Comment: Don't use write-only property, try to use SetXXX method to provide write-only semantics.

Comment: What's the difference? Same end result...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from [Write Only Property MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25dey2kc.aspx)

> Sometimes you want the consuming code to be able to set a value but
>   not discover what it is. For example, **sensitive data, such as a
>   social registration number or a password, needs to be protected from
>   access by any component that did not set it**. In these cases, you can
>   use a WriteOnly property to set the value.

Comment: This may be an edge case, that's possible, but @adam, there are hundreds of examples of programming language capabilities that are not used or not practical that exist due to demand for flexibility. Just because I can set my couch on fire, doesn't mean that it's meant to be flammable.

Comment: @user3308043 If found in some languages I would agree.. but in every, major, language, I would disagree.  When found in such a high number of languages, it is evident to me there must be a general valuable purpose. Such as the example provided on MSDN (linked).

Comment: Great link! So there is a valid reason.

Answer (score 1):

No, never. It makes simply no sense to never read it.

Well, in hardware it may be an edge case - hardware can react to address writes and take it as command ;) But that is outside the scope of the question and can be implied to be a read.

Answer (score 1):

With Writeonly, you can change a variable, without being capable to read it. Meaning that your data is more secure, this can be useful for sensitive data, such as IP Addresses, phone numbers, emails etc.

Comment: Yeah. And given that the data is never accessed, what use is it to store it in the first place?